# Credit Note functionality not working in Magento

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, creditmemo

Hope someone here can assist me!

It seems I'm having a problem with creating a credit note in Magento 1.7.0.2 (Yes, I know it's a slightly older version - Going to update to 1.9 in due course).

Whenever you start a credit note on an order that has been invoiced and shipped, the place where items and quantities are filled in seems to be greyed out - I have no option to add items to be refunded!

I've disabled any non-standard modules and this hasn't helped and I've also re-indexed and cleared cache (just incase!).

I've posted a screenshot below.

[image: Issue with adding items to refund - Greyed out button and no items visible]

(Please note, the other information such as address and payment info are visible - I've just blanked them out in the screengrab!)

Comment: what do the logs say?
var/log/*.log

Comment: Hi Detzler,

I've just FTP'ed and checked the system.log file but this is completely empty. I've no other log files in /var/log/

I've been trying all weekend but still no luck on this issue!

Comment: there should be an exception.log .. check the config in backend, is logging active?

Comment: Hello @Detzler, thanks for getting back so quickly and for your assistance! 

So I enabled logging (didn't even think that it may be turned off!), SSH'ed to the server and rebooted the LAMP stack and then tried to create a new credit memo - I now have the following in the log.

'2014-10-27T11:32:50+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/sales/order/creditmemo/create/items/renderer/default.phtml'

I've had a quick google for this but can't seem to get much further - Are you or another SE'er able to assist? :)

Comment: Try to copy the entire directory (app/design/adminhtml/) from a clean magento v1.7 into your project.
If it woun't help, deactivate some extensions in the community and local scope, maybe there is an evildoer. (Dont't forget to clear cache)

Comment: @Detzler got it! A fresh adminhtml directory followed by refreshing the cache and flushing the Magento cache for good measure has solved the problem! Thank you so much for your assistance Detzler! I'm new to SE, but if I'm reading correctly, then feel free to submit as an answer and I will mark it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to copy the entire directory (app/design/adminhtml/) from a clean magento v1.7 into your project. If it woun't help, deactivate some extensions in the community and local scope, maybe there is an evildoer. (Dont't forget to clear cache)